# Non-uniqueness of smooth compactification

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, compactifications

Let $U$ be a smooth quasi-projective variety. Does there always exist a smooth compactification of $U$? If not always when can we have smooth compactification? 
In particular, suppose $X$ is a singular projective variety and $U$ is the smooth locus. The question is does there always exist a smooth projective variety $Y$ containing $U$? If we add the condition that $U$ is open in $Y$ is $Y$ uniquely determined upto isomorphism?

Comment: You should search for "resolution of singularities" to answer the question about existence. About uniqueness: in dimension at least 2, no, because of blow-ups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main idea is this: You can always find an $X$ such that $X\supseteq U$ and $X\setminus U\supseteq \Sigma := \mathrm{Sing} X$. Then in characteristic zero apply Hironaka's resolution theorem, which says that there exists a resolution of singularities $\pi:Y\to X$ such that $\pi$ is an isomorphism over $X\setminus \Sigma\supseteq U$. In particular, $\pi^{-1}: U\hookrightarrow Y$ gives an embedding.

In positive characteristic resolution is not known in general and similarly this embedding result is not known either (although I am not saying that knowing this would prove the existence of resolutions).

There is actually a newer, expanded version of Kollár's paper in book form: 
[Lectures on Resolution of Singularities](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8449.html).

And of course it is not unique as long as $U$ itself is not projective, since as you can always blow-up $Y$ outside of $U$.

Comment: A remark: though $U$ doesnotdetermine $Y$, for any cohomology theory that factorizes through Voevodsky′s motives the image $H(Y)\to H(U)$ is canonical and functorial (this is the zeroth level of the weight filtration). One can also look at weight complexes. In characteristic $p$ one can prove a somewhat similar result for any cohomology whose target is a $Z[1/p]$-linear category.

Comment: @Mikhail: I'm sorry, but I don't see your point. Could you explain?

Comment: So, smooth compactifications are certainly not unique; yet this non-uniqueness can be controlled to a certain extent.

Comment: @Mikhail, I'm sorry, but I still don't understand how this is more control. Perhaps my problem is what Artie mentions that I can't read half of your comment...

Comment: ....or mine, now....

Comment: Sorry for not noticing your comment earlier.:) The answer is that weight complexes are functorial up to homotopy, and  weight spectral sequences are functorial starting from $E_2$ for any (co)homology theory that factors through motives..

Comment: @Mikhail: I'm sorry, but what I meant was that in my opinion this is not what the question was. One could mention more traditional facts in this regard, for example that Hodge theory of $U$ is (usually) computed via choosing a $Y$ such that $Y\setminus U$ is an snc divisor, but the result is independent of the actual $Y$. In some sense, if I understand correctly, this is sort of the same thing as what you are saying. Yet, $Y$ itself is still not unique.

Comment: Dear Sandor: yes, you are quite right. I have have just meant that a significant generalization of this result is now available.

Comment: OK, cool. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 8):

In characteristic 0, yes, yes, no. Check out Kollar's paper:

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508332

In characteristic p, unknown.